# Python: How to read the file between elements in xml

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I would like to read the string between  and 
Is there a way to read it by using ElementTree in python?

May i know how to read the tag title2?

```
<head>
    <title>My Podcasts</title>
          <title2>My_Podcast2</title2>
    <dateCreated>Sun, 07 Mar 2010 15:53:26 GMT</dateCreated>
    <dateModified>Sun, 07 Mar 2010 15:53:26 GMT</dateModified>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Each ElementTree node has a `tail` attribute.  The `text` attribute gets the text inside the node, and the `tail` attribute gets the text following the node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='target.xml')

root = tree.getroot()


for child in root:
    print(child.tag, child.text)
```

output:

```
title My Podcasts
dateCreated Sun, 07 Mar 2010 15:53:26 GMT
dateModified Sun, 07 Mar 2010 15:53:26 GMT
```